# Easy way to create GUI in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I have tried using Tkinter but it is not so easy to create Attractive GUI application.Is there an application or online website where I can use Drag and Drop approach to create GUI Interface in python.or some other easy way Also reply with some Intutive  references or tutorial if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Pyqt seems like a good option here. It's a cross platform GUI framework that comes with qt designer, an applicatiom that let's you build GUIs by dragging and dropping widgets on a canvas.

Here's a basic [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/basic-gui-pyqt-tutorial/) you can follow. There's also a series of videos included with imformation on how to download and install pyqt

Comment: It's the only one that comes to mind with a designer, which is what he is looking for

Comment: what I am looking for is Drag and drop application Such as in Visual Basics.

Comment: And qt designer does exactly that